# Eclipse won't detect Openj9 SDK as JRE 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having some issues trying to Eclipse detect this JDK: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u282-b08_openj9-0.24.0/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_windows_openj9_8u282b08_openj9-0.24.0.zip
If I download it and create a new "Installed JRE" entry, it detects the libs but when I go to Execution Environments it does not show the JRE. Has somebody had this issue? How to fix this?

I'm using Eclipse Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0) Build id: 20201210-1552 on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Did you Apply the Installed JREs preference page before going to the Execution Environments page?

Comment: Yes I did. And closed Eclipse again, and reinstalled the JDK...The whole deal.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try it with eclipse Oxygen builds.

jdk8 isn't very compatible with IDEs developed for java9+

Comment: Yes, I tried one build a bit newer than Oxygen: Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
Build id: 20191212-1212. It worked, recognized the openj9 (jdk8u282-b08) and openj9-jdk-11.0.9. I managed to run JBoss 7.3, however I had to install JBoss Tools because when I tried to add a new JBoss Server the menu for JBoss was not there. I found that a bit odd, but since JBoss Tools worked it's all fine.Thanks for the tip!

Comment: My pleasure. glad it helped.